# Laravel Eloquent polymorphic one-to-one?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to setup a polymorphic one-to-one relationship (the polymorphic equivalent of has_one and belongs_to).I've got an `Address` model, and there are several other models that I want to have one address. However, I'm confused by the wording of the docs. I've seen the `morphMany` method, but my question is: should I use `morphMany` even though I only want it to have one address, or is there something like a `morphOne` method I should be using?

EDIT: My `Address` model has these fields, just to help visualize:

```
Schema::create('addresses', function ($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('street');
    $table->string('street_more')->nullable();
    $table->string('city');
    $table->string('state')->nullable();
    $table->string('country');
    $table->string('postal_code');
    $table->integer('addressable_id');
    $table->string('addressable_type');
});
```

Comment: This isn't the model. This is the migration.

Comment: @DennisBraga I meant the structure of the model. Thanks for catching that! I've clarified in the post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, there is a *morphOne* method and I think is the one you should use in this case: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L811 .

Also you can use

```
$table->morphs('addressable');
```

instead of

```
$table->integer('addressable_id');
$table->string('addressable_type');
```

I've used morphOne in a custom package for L4 and works pretty well.

Comment: That's great! It's just not documented then. Thank you very much. Re: `$table->morphs`, I find it more readable to stick them in there myself separately, but thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the function is now called "morphOne" https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L792

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, I think this is better than morphOne that not supported.

```
  public function address()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'addressable_id','id')
                   ->where('addressable_type', 'App\Model');
  }
```

Comment: This is only one-directional. Using Laravel's polymorphic relationships will allow you to get the "addressable things" from the Address model.